# Add Loadbalancer to aws cli run instance command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, aws-cli

I have been using the following AWS CLi command t launch EC2 Instances which works well but i would like to add these instances to my Load-balancer at the same time if possible??

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t1.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx --subnet-id subnet-xxxxxxxx
```

To Manually Register i could use

```
elb-register-instances-with-lb MyLoadBalancer --instances i-xxxxxxx
```

but i want to add this to the launch process like autoscaling does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ["Launching Instances with User Data".](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) You can pass in an arbitrary shell script to be run after the instance launches.  This includes AWS CLI commands, like elb-register-instances-with-lb.

On aws ec2 run-instances, you can include user data inline or as a file. You can also include user data when autoscaling.

From the [run-instances documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RunInstances.html):

```
[-d user_data | -f filename]


-d, --user-data user_data
The base64-encoded MIME user data for the instances.

Type: String

Default: None

Required: No

Example: -d s3-bucket:my-logs


-f, --user-data-file filename
The file name of the user data for the instances.

Type: String

Default: None

Required: No

Example: -f user-data.txt
```